# Function stops after POST request

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code. I need to make a couple of AJAX requests. Like this:

```
function Test() {
    $.post("test.php", { 'test': "test1" }, function (result) {
        alert(result);
    });

    alert ("First done");

    $.post("test2.php", { 'test': "test2" }, function (result) {
        alert(result);
    });

    alert ("Second done");;
}
```

I see the first `alert(result)`, but I not see `alert("First done");` Why? How can I fix this?

P.S. No. alert(result); perfect work and return value witout exception.

Thank you all. I found a mistake.

Comment: and what first `alert(result);` return? error.?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: jQuery ajax functions are asynchronous by default, this means that both "first done" and "second done" alerts should happen before alert(result). You dont see those alerts at all? there is an obvious sequence problem in your code, but nothing that could prevent the alerts from happening pops up

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/HYBEm/. We cannot help you if we cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/mE3LZ/1/

Comment: *"I found a mistake."* What was it? Don't just accept an answer for the sake of accepting it. What was the problem? If you don't think that the problem/solution would be helpful to someone else, please delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use $.ajax instead of $.post and specify `async false`

```
    function Test() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "test.php",
        data: {
            'test': "test1"
        },
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        async: false
    });

    alert("First done");

    $.post("test2.php", {
        'test': "test2"
    }, function (result) {
        alert(result);
    });

    alert("Second done");;
}
```